# Inserting data into database with python/sqlite3 by recognising the column name

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I've got a problem that I don't know how to solve, I've tried many solutions but always getting that Operational error: near...

```
def insert_medicine_to_table():
        con = sqlite3.connect('med_db3.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        table_name = 'medicines'
        column_name = "présentation"
        value = 'Boîte de 2 seringues pré-remplies'
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO medicines {} VALUES (?)".format(column_name), value)
        con.commit()
        con.close()


sqlite3.OperationalError: near "présentation": syntax error
```

The goal here is that either the script or python has to recognize the field (column name) and insert the value into "that" field, like the following:

```
fields = ['présentation', 'princeps', 'distributeur_ou_fabriquant', 'composition', 'famille', 'code_atc', 'ppv', 'prix_hospitalier', 'remboursement', 'base_de_remboursement__ppv', 'nature_du_produit']
values = ['Boîte de 2 seringues pré-remplies', 'Oui', 'SANOFI', 'Héparine', 'Anticoagulant héparinique', 'B01AB01', '43.80', '27.40', 'Oui', '43.80', 'Médicament']
```

That is one entry in the database. The problem here is that other entries can or not have one or more values for some field, and also the fields are not presented in the same order in other entries.

It has to recognize each field in the database table and insert each value into the right column.

Answer (score 0):

The problem causing your error is that your SQL isn't valid. The statement you are trying to execute is:

```
INSERT INTO medicines présentation VALUES (?)
```

The statement you want to execute is:

```
INSERT INTO medicines ("présentation") VALUES (?)
```

As far as your larger question is concerned, if you create both the list of columns `("présentation")` and list of parameter markers `(?)` and build the query using them, you're most of the way there.

If a field can have multiple values supplied for each "entry" in your database, you may need to change your database design to handle that.  You'll at least need to figure out how you want to handle the situation, but that would be a matter for a different question.

Comment: Thanks man, but I did solve the problem by zipping the lists into a dictionnary